# json-rpc event-machine stand alone service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What am I doing wrong?
I try to run example code from [json-rpc](https://github.com/helios-technologies/json-rpc) documentation. Togather with EventMachine:

```
require 'json-rpc'
require 'thin'

class AsyncApp
  include JsonRpc
  AsyncResponse = [-1, {}, []].freeze
  def call env
    rpc_call(env)
  end

  def rpc_sum a, b
    result = Rpc::AsyncResult.new
    EventMachine::next_tick do
      result.reply a + b
      result.succeed
    end
    result
  end
end

EM::run do
  Thin::Server.start('0.0.0.0', 8999) do
    map('/'){ run AsyncApp.new }
  end
end
```

There is no error on this server console appears.
The result is on transport layer on the json-rpc client is:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I've try same client with jimson gem implememtation - it work fine but does not support EventMachine and async calls. (Show example if you know how it possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at default "welcome" page assigned to route "/".
I do not try to go with browser to "/", but only try to connect by rpc client.
Some how default "welcome" page route "/" rule is not overwrited by `map("/"){...}` rule.

The solution is rewrite route rule like this `map("/rpc"){...}`